# Actor + playframework + slick query

Tags: playframework, akka, slick

I am new to akka + playframework. I have been using direct slick run method in play async action method. run(. … ) method returns Future[T]. Now my question is - will it be okay to use actor ask method within the play async action in controller to execute slick run method?

```
package controllers

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc._
import services.actorServices.TestActor

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@Singleton
class ActorTestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder, executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  val testActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[TestActor])
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout.apply(2 second)


  def test: Action[AnyContent] =Action.async{
    (testActor ? "test").mapTo[String].map(string => Ok(string))
  }

}


package services.actorServices

import akka.actor.Actor
import services.dbServices.HomePageDAO

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


class TestActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "test" =>
      HomePageDAO.getSlogan.map { seqOfString =>
        sender() ! seqOfString.head
      }

  }
}
```

Actually ask does not work with a method which compute in Future :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You don't want to do this:

```
HomePageDAO.getSlogan.map { seqOfString =>
        sender() ! seqOfString.head
      }
```

"sender" might change (actually, it probably will) until Future completes. What you can do is to use `pipeTo` and reply to sender when Future completes.

```
HomePageDAO.getSlogan pipeTo sender()
```

Personal opinion: Actor is superfluous in this case. You don't need it. Just use `HomePageDAO` instead in `ActorTestController`.

Comment: thanks for your help- it is working. I was also thinking that "Actor is superfluous in this case".